# Change background-color of an element of the same class name, depending on the level in the DOM tree

Tags: html, css, nested, less, cycle

I have this basic HTML structure:

```html
<div class="section-container">
  <div class="section-expander">
  <div class="section-content">
    <div class="some-irrelevant-stuff"></div>
    <div class="section-children">

      <div class="section-container">
        <div class="section-expander">
        <div class="section-content">
          <div class="some-irrelevant-stuff"></div>
          <div class="section-children">

            <div class="section-container">
              <div class="section-expander">
              <div class="section-content">
                <div class="some-irrelevant-stuff"></div>
                <div class="section-children">

                  ...

                </div> <!-- Closing 3rd level section-children -->
              </div> <!-- Closing 3rd level section-content -->
              </div> <!-- Closing 3rd level section-expander -->
            </div> <!-- Closing 3rd level section-container -->

          </div> <!-- Closing 2nd level section-children -->
        </div> <!-- Closing 2nd level section-content -->
        </div> <!-- Closing 2nd level section-expander -->
      </div> <!-- Closing 2nd level section-container -->

    </div> <!-- Closing 1st level section-children -->
  </div> <!-- Closing 1st level section-content -->
  </div> <!-- Closing 1st level section-expander -->
</div> <!-- Closing 1st level section-container -->
```

Here is a visual representation:
[image: Two nested blocks inside one]

Maybe the only thing that is not self explanatory is that .section-expander are the colored lines on the left.

So, my question is if there is a way using only LESS, without adding new classes or using JS:

1) change the background-color of the .section-expander on the left, depending on their nesting level in the DOM

2) cycle the background-color of .section-content, again depending on the nesting level, as you can see in the screenshot (I cycle lightgray and white).

The easiest way I could come up with is:

```css
.section-container {

  .section-expander { background-color: green; }
  .section-content {
    background-color: lightgray;
    
    .section-expander { background-color: blue; }
    .section-content {
      background-color: white;
      
      .section-expander { background-color: red; }
      .section-content {
        background-color: lightgray;
        
        ...
        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I feel it is not very clever doing it this way. I guess I should use some sort of a LESS cycle, but after hours of trying I really can't come up with something that works as intended. Could someone help me coming up with something better?

Comment: @Phiter What is the problem?

Comment: You should get a way with nth-of-type.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the following declarations and your structure:

```
$A : section-container;
$B : section-expander;
$C : section-content;
$D : section-children;
```

your final CSS will look like this:

```
.$A .$B { background-color: green;}
.$D .$B {  background-color: blue; }
.$D .$D .$B {  background-color: red;}
```

... and, in the end, that's what gets the job done and makes sense to the browser, regardless of what tools you use in order to write less code and get the same result.

If you feel you're more efficient by writing less code, use some variables names (as I did), to shorten your syntax, but make sure you don't hit too hard on code readability. Mind maintainability.

If you worry about the length of the resulting CSS or browser speed/performance, don't. Differences in length of your CSS don't really matter. It's other things that impact a lot more on page speed.

To be totally frank, in your shoes I would worry about the hours you spent trying to optimize code nobody else will see.

---

Anyway, here's how I'd personally do it, in SASS. I'm a bit nuts about keeping selector specificity and `z-index`(unrelated here) levels low:

```sass
$I : some-irrelevant-stuff;
$S : section-;

.#{$S}container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 1rem 0 1rem 1rem;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    padding: 1rem;
    .$I {
        padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 0;
    }

    &::before {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: teal;
        height: 100%;
        left: -1rem;
        top: 0;
        width: 1rem;
        content: '';
        .#{$S}children & {
            background-color: #369;
            .#{$S}children & {
                background-color: #900;
            }
        }
    }
    .#{$S}container {
        background-color: white;
        .#{$S}container {
            background-color: #f3f3f3;
        }
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/m1qsxygc/

**Note** I also simplified your markup a bit.

Comment: When you say "that nobody else will see" you're ignoring the [Bus factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_factor).